# Are there any tutorials on version 10 notebook templating and report generation? Are there missing docs?

Tags: bugs, templates

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

I am trying to understand the new templating in version 10. While there is a [general documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WorkingWithTemplates.html) with links to docs for each new function, so far I am unable to find any report generation worked examples of what a user may do after they open File > New > Template Notebook. Additionally when I press the help button on the template notebook it seems there is documentation missing:

[image]

When you type "ReportGeneration" in the docs this is what you get:

[image]

Templates were first introduced in the Finance Platform -- which is essentially a version of Mathematica with a few other functions. Rather than have report generation functions without any coherent description of how a user can start from scratch and make a template and an automated report, the Finance Platform has a wealth of material, including a tour:

[image]

...detailed extensive documentation:

[image]

...a specific palette that contains links to the tour, the extensive documentation and a video:

[image]

**All of this stuff is missing from my OS X version 10. Is it present in Windows?**

Comment: fyi, there seems to be other missing documentations not added, even though it shows there. Here is a post on community on a missing command even though the item shows up on help, clicking on it shows it is missing http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/293654?p_p_auth=QvP6n2NJ  it is `MaterialData[]` in this page `guide/PhysicsAndChemistryDataAndComputation`

Comment: @Nasser `MaterialData` was something I looked at the other day and got a weird $Aborted as an argument.

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch There is "Generate a Notebook from a Template" [link](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/string-file-html-templating/generate-a-notebook-from-a-template.html) and on System/ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb is a working example.

Comment: @Lou that short example generates the notebook from the template. My question is about creating templates.

Comment: In 10.0.1 at least the help button works. I haven't found the tour yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confirmed bug by WRI tech support

Comment: Glat to hear it's coming

Answer (score 6):

John Fultz gave a great talk about the templating system at the European Wolfram Technology Conference in 2014 - http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference-eu/2014/presentations/Fultz_ReportGeneration.nb

As requested, here's a video of John doing madlibs http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=Report%20Generation&v=1096

Comment: That's useful. Is there any screen cast maybe?

Comment: @Kuba updated for you

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame it is not directly linked to docs for `GenerateDocument` etc.

Comment: I don't work directly for WRI anymore, but I'll suggest links to broadcast and conf talks. There are many ideas for the documentation that are exciting/"neat"...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe they renamed it. You should search the help for "AutomatedReports" this will bring you to guide/AutomatedReports. Or on the web: [AutomatedReports](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AutomatedReports.html).
Some small examples and more details are presented at [Automated Report Generation](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/automated-report-generation/index.html) and the links therein.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't address the question. There is heaps of stuff that is simply missing

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch your recent edits show that there is a bigger issue. However, you should contact WRI to address this and to find out if it isn't an intentional deficit of Mathematica compared to their Finance Platform.